# pandas column change because of semicolon using to_csv

Tags: pandas

My panda df contains one value as this::

'A flexible transcutaneous transformer utilizing amorphous magnetic fiber for an artificial heart system is reported. The transformer can transmit electrical energy of 20 W with an efficiency of over **90%; the** primary current density does not greatly depend on the relative displacement of the coils. The temperature rise of the transformer was about 6 degrees C in a phantom test.<>'

Now, when I use 'to_csv' to save my df, it splits this value at ; and shows two column for this vale.
Because of which my whole values are shifted by one column.

Comment: df.to_csv('filename123.csv',header ='column_names', encoding='utf-8')

Comment: Not sure about this but please try `df.to_csv('filename123.csv', header ='column_names', encoding='utf-8', line_terminator='n')`

Comment: Thanx, now it is working