# Pandas split string value with ";" inside into multiple columns in to_csv

Tags: python, pandas, export-to-csv

Some lines in my df has the character ';' inside of it, for example: "blabla;bla;bla". When I use to_csv with default parameters, it splits the string into multiple columns, in the above example it would split into three columns: "blabla", "bla", "bla". How can I use to_csv to keep using ',' as separator but maintaining the string value as it is ?

Comment: `to_csv` doesn't split anything, it generates text. There's no problem with `;` in a field if the field separator is `,`. Did you try to open the file in Excel by double-clicking on it? In that case the problem is that Excel uses your locale settings to find the field separator. In European countries that's `;` because `,` is the decimal separator. If you used `Insert` from the `Data` menu you'd be able to specify the separator you wanted

Comment: If you intend to use the file with Excel it's better to use `to_excel`. Excel supports numbers and dates natively so there's no chance of confusion.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, as I said in my question, it was indeed splitting the text, there's also another similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37069657/pandas-column-change-because-of-semicolon-using-to-csv), but the solutions did not solve my problem.

Comment: Text is text, it doesn't split or have columns. It's reader applications that split. I use Pandas to process CSV and Excel invoice files from multiple countries and formats, so having to handle and often detect `;` or `,` is quite common. And the default in CSV is the Comma, ie `,`, not `;`. `;` iss a convention started by spreadsheet programs like Excel 30-40 years ago to handle European data, where `,` is part of numeric data. `to_csv` *always*` uses `,` unless you tell it otherwise. You don't have to force anything, that's the default. It's the clients that have issues

Comment: You haven't posted any example of the output, but there are only two ways to get into such trouble. First, you used `sep=';'` but some text field also includes `;`. That's no different from using `,` and having text columns that contain `,`. The solution is to quote that field. You can quote text fields only with `quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC`. The other possibility is trying to open a file using `,` with Excel or another program in a locale that assumes `;` is the list separator, eg all European countries. You'll either get all text in a single column, or columns split on `;` found in text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What if you use the `quoting` option when doing the `to_csv` operation, so that you can escape the semicolon within the df values?

```
df.to_csv('test.csv', sep=';', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
```

Comment: Just adding the parameter `quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL` solved the problem. Thank you.

Comment: A better option would be to use [csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC) to quote *only* text fields. Otherwise numeric columns will also get quoted and treated as text by spreadsheets or other consumers

Comment: yes you're right @PanagiotisKanavos. thanks for adding that point